# Como pegar o conteúdo da condição da cláusula JOIN

Tags: query, regex

Eu tenho a seguinte situação que pode ser vista nesse [link](http://regex101.com/r/kR4zV3).

A expressão é:

```
/((^|\s)(right|inner|left)\sjoin\s(.*?)on\s(.*?)(?=(inner|right|where)?))+/gmi
```

Preciso pegar as condições que estão dentro do `on`, mais as outras informações que já estão sendo capturadas.

Alguém tem uma dica?

Comment: Pode descrever melhor qual o objetivo? Você está tentando processar código SQL? Talvez seja melhor procurar um parser pronto do que usar regex, elas não vão ser 100%.

Comment: Eu necessido de criar um parser, pois os prontos não se adequatam tanto ao que necessito, mas o objetivo desse da pergunta é que preciso pegar o montante das condições para depois separar cada condição, caso tenha mais de uma.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei a origem da sua expressão (e muito menos se o resultado obtido era realmente o intencionado) mas a adaptei de modo a conseguir os valores precedidos pelo `on`.

Então, tente com [essa](http://regex101.com/r/nO4mO5) expressão:

```
^(?<expressaocompleta>(?:^|\s)(?<tipojoin>right|inner|left)\sjoin\s(?<tabelasjoin>.*)\son\s(?<clausulas>.*(?<fatorcondicional>inner|right|where(?<condicao>.*))?))$
```

*É um pouco grande, mas comentei-a para ficar um pouco mais intuitivo*